# Extension method could not read and accepting the arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I got some trouble with this error message

> 'Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFrame' does not contain a definition for
>   'ToBitmap' and no extension method 'ToBitmap' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFrame' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

the extension ToBitmap is already made, but the program can't read it, what i have to do to fixed it???

btw this is the program syntax

```
private void Sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
     using(var frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
     {
          if (frame != null)
          {
                if (_mode == CameraMode.Color)
                {
                     Camera.Source = frame.toBitmap();
                }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: are you including the namespace declaration at the top for where your extension resides?

Comment: Could paste the declaration of toBitmap method? toBitmap or ToBitmap? Typo?

Comment: no... can u tell me how? im newbie... is that like

Comment: no its just typo when i write it down to here... i wasn't copy-paste. it was in different Laptop... so  is that like 'using project.' ??

Comment: Can you write the declaration of your extension method i.e. 
public static void ExtensionMethod(this type abc,type b)

Comment: You need to add the namespace that `ToBitmap` is declared inside. `using Namespace.ProjectWhereToBitmapIs`

Comment: Moreover, the declaration has to be inside static class (if it isn't).

Comment: what is Namespace for.. im sorry,, i m newbie here...